# Direct diff local files to commit in Git

Tags: git, git-diff

I want to run a diff between a commit and my local files, using an external diff-tool, without temp files for my local.  I am running git on Windows.

I am currently attempting this using:`git difftool --dir-diff <commit> -- <path_to_local_dir>`.  This approach works fine, however the `<path_to_local>` is then represented by a **temp** folder in AppData.  For most uses, this is fine.

However, using an external diff tool (in my case BeyondCompare4), the diff tool provides the functionality of "Copying" specific changes from `<commit>` to `<path_to_local>`.  This is where my issue comes in.  If Git forces using **temp** folders for local files, that "Copying" behavior is useless since it is only modifying the temporary files.

I know I could write a script that copies the contents of **temp** to my local files after a save, but I am looking for a more elegant solution.

As a sidenote, Mercurial appears to support the requested behavior by default (Only creates Temp files when local files don't already exist)

**So, in short, is there a way to force `git difftool` to actually use local files rather than creating and using temp files for my local files that already exist?**

Edit: Word Usage

Answer (score 3):

As I do with many things, I ended up overthinking this issue.

Turns out, as stated in the git [difftool documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool#Documentation/git-difftool.txt---no-symlinks), `git difftool` uses symlinks by default for files in the working tree.

The full explanation of symbolic links is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).  The quick explanation is that if you modify a symbolic link to a file, you are effectively and actually modifying that file.

On Windows, the issue becomes a bit more unclear since Git's default behavior is `--no-symlinks`, but the end result should be the same.

Short answer:  Just click *Save* on the **temp** file.  The changes should show up in your local files.

Comment: Thanks for overthinking, because the symlink editing is not working for me.